# spring security with custom filter remote access gets 401 HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required, but not when using localhost

Tags: spring, security, filter, spring-security

I have a spring security web application, with the following application context configuration using the spring security 3.1 namespace:

```
<security:http create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationFilter" position="FIRST" />
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias='authenticationManager'>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='customUserDetailsService' />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="restAuthenticationFilter" class="com...security.RestAuthenticationFilter"/>
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com...security.RestUserDetailsService"/>
```

When I go to my browser and enter the URL `http://localhost/rest/user/getByUsername?userName=foo&passWord=bar&deviceId=1234` my custom filter gets called, and the user is authenticated by his user name, password, and deviceId, and he is allowed to retrieve his user information from the URL. However, I need to test whether this works from the android which is on the same network. So, if I do `ifconfig` and grab my local ip address from `ifconfig`, replace localhost with it, and type enter the URL in my browser `http://<local ip address>/rest/user/getByUsername?userName=foo&passWord=bar&deviceId=1234` in my browser, then I get HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource and the browser brings up a popup form to login using username and password.

I want my app to authorize the same way via remote request as it does with localhost.

Your help will be so, so greatly appreciated. Thanks pals :)

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I see problem in your configuration

```
<security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationFilter" position="FIRST" />
```

You should put your filter after CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER to allow proper Spring Security functionality.

```
<security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER"/>
```

Please look here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters